# How do I configure the Users context/table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

With the new ASP.NET MVC 5 Preview released, how do I configure the Users context/table?

In MVC 4 I would just use my own User class and then point the WebSecurity initialize to it, tike this:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient", userTableName, userIdColumn, userNameColumn, autoCreateTables);
```

I wish to add additional properties to the Users class - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UserStore and User classes are there to make EF based implementations easier, but you can always drop down and implement your own custom IUserStore and pass in your own DbContext.

I can provide a more detailed example if you need.

Comment: I would really like to see an example. I tried implementing my own, but ended up with some claim identity problems, causing the AntiFogeryToken to fail. Happens when I use the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser for my own User class.

Comment: @Hao Kung,  I would like to see a top down example.  I also want to avoid the new table for "MyUsers".  Could you please include Roles with custom fields in the example?

Comment: @Hao Kung, would you provide an example?

Comment: The Migration sample is probably the most detailed example of a custom EF implementation: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-universal-provider-data-for-membership-and-user-profiles-to-aspnet-identity

Answer (score 2):

I think, this can solve your issue:

---

In **Models \ IdentityModels.cs** you can redefine your own User model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    /* identity field from database */
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Internal { get; set; }

    public string UserFullName { get; set; }

    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
        : base()
    {
        Internal = false;
    }

    public ApplicationUser(string userName)
        : base(userName)
    {
        Internal = false;
    }

}
```

now you can change mapping of defaults AspNet tables using **OnModelCreating()** overridding and **ToTable()** methode:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Change the name of the table to be Users instead of AspNetUsers
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("User_Claim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("User_Login");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("User_Role");
    }
}
```

Finally you will see in the database the following tables:
**User, Role, User_Role, User_Claim, User_Login** instead of AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetUsersRoles, AspNetUsersClaims, AspNetUserLogins.

Of course the **User** table will contain additional fields: **UserId** (int identity), **Internal**, **UserFullName** and **UserEmail**.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a sample from https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample. This is based on the ASP.NET MVC template that shipped with [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013 Preview Refresh](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309552) (Supports English version of VS2013 Preview only) Once you have this Preview Refresh installed you can do the same for ASP.NET Web Forms and SPA applications.

Following are the steps to Run this project

```
Open the solution
Build and run
Register a user ---- Notice that the user registration field only has user name and password
Let's ask for a birthdate option from the user while registering an account.
Goto Nuget Package Manager console and run "Enable-Migrations"
Goto Models\AppModel.cs and uncomment BirthDate property in the MyUser class
Goto Models\AccountViewModels.cs and uncomment BirthDate property in RegisterViewModel
Goto AccountController and in Register Action and have the following code var user = new MyUser() { UserName = model.UserName,BirthDate=model.BirthDate }; //var user = new MyUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
Goto Views\Account\Register.cshtml and uncomment the HTML markup to add a BirthDate column
Goto Nuget Package Manager console and run "Add-Migration BirthDate"
Goto Nuget Package Manager console and run "Update-Database"
Run the application
When you register a user then you can enter BirthDate as well
```

Comment: I already seen that example, but it creates a MyUser, I really want my own User class, not Entity Frameworks user class. So when using the above solution I get a MyUsers table in the database - which is not wanted.